# How to run detox for react native on windows?

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

Is that possible to run detox on windows ? if not is there any alternative to test react native apps on windows environment ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer no. I was also planning to use it when I noticed that the documentation talks about Mac OS only. So after a little digging I found this GitHub discussion https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/333. On alternatives I plan to explore Appium as mentioned in the React Native testing documents here https://reactnative.dev/docs/testing-overview